# How to group in a specific order in Kendo ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, grouping, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Grid in ASP.NET MVC and I've grouped my datas.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Correspondent>(Model.Correspondents)
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Service)
                .Title("Service")
                .Hidden(true);
            
            columns.Bound(p => p.Name)
                .Title("Name")
                .ClientTemplate(RenderCorrespondentName().ToHtmlString());
            
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Group(groups => groups.Add(p => p.Service))
        )
    )
```

We can see that I'm grouping my datas by service.

Now, and I can't find a way to do it, is to sort thoses services in a specific order : I'd like one service to always come last.

I've seen somewhere that you can specify an order for your grouping if you pass a list of items in the right order. In my case I do not know what I can get in the service : What I know is I might have a service that is null (Or "None") and if so, I'd like to put this group at the end.

Sorry for potential grammatical errors, I hope I was clear enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I suceeded in what I wanted to do in a very cheeky way.

As I saw that the groups where sorted in ascending order I named my specific service "ZZZ" so that he would be at the end of the list, then in JavaScript I find and edit the "ZZZ" in what I wanted, in this case "Other".